# Control a discord.py bot from the terminal/command line it runs in

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I've gone through the [documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#), and I can't find a way to control the bot from the terminal/command line/etc in any way.

For example, if I had a `flip` command on the bot, which would choose either 0 or 1 and send a message for heads or tails respectively, I'd like to be able to enter `flip` into the terminal and have it send its respective message to #general.

Is there any way that this would be possible?

Comment: yeah, you could use inputs and check if the input equal a certain command then invoke that function.

Comment: how would I do that then?

Comment: just using `input()` halts the bot, so I can't use that

Answer (score -1):

If you want to control the bot from the terminal, try this maybe:

```
import discord, random
from discord.ext import commands


min = 0
max = 1


channel = client.get_channel(123456789) # This will be the channel id


terminal_cmd = input('')

if terminal_cmd == 'flip':
    channel.send(random.randint(min, max))
```

I'm pretty sure this would work, if not try scout through stack overflow or github for answers. Try using different wordings in your searches aswell.

Answer (score -1):

@Kai code won't work.
Try this instead.

```py
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")
token = "token"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    while not client.is_closed():
        c = input("text/command")
        if "yourcommand" in c:
            command = client.get_command("yourcommand")
            await command()

@client.command()
async def yourcommand():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    chioce = ["0", "1"]
    content = random.choice(chioce)
    await channel.send(content)

client.run(token)
```